# Peewee: Packet sequence number wrong - got 2 expected 1

Tags: mysql, peewee

I am using PyMySQL as a MySQL library and they have discussed this problem [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/422). They asked to set threadsafety. How do I do it in peewee as my app is multi-process and having a pool of two processes like this:

I am not able to produce this error on local machine, happening on Amazon based MySQL

Answer (score 0):

The `threadsafety` parameter you're referring to seems to be part of the DB-API 2.0 spec. The problem is not with peewee but with how you are attempting to use the mysql driver.

Comment: Whatever it is, it's quite pathetic error and so far I am unable to solve. I do believe it's more related to `PyMySQL` than `peewee` and guys at `PyMySQL` are not being so helpful.

Comment: Shit sucks...you tried using MySQLdb (I think it's packaged as mysql-python)?

Comment: `PyMYSQL` is a python based driver and not related to `MySQLDb`